# Bespoke C++ Windows app crashing and producing an empty dmp file

Tags: c++, crash, dump

We have an in-house c++ app that we are running via task scheduler.  We are attempting to trace an issue with the app which causes a crash, a windows event and we would usually look for the .dmp file to enable us to track the issue in visual studio.

However, these windows dump files [appname. dmp] is zero bytes.

Is there anyone out there that knows the potential causes of the .dmp file being empty, please?

Sample event log below in case it helps.

Many thanks for any help and thoughts :)

Andy P

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"> 
- <System> 
<Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
<EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
<Level>2</Level> 
<Task>100</Task> 
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-11-09T15:48:04.642807400Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>5214</EventRecordID> 
<Channel>Application</Channel> 
<Computer>redacted> 
<Security /> 
</System> 
- <EventData> 
<Data>redacted.exe</Data> 
<Data>1.0.0.1</Data> 
<Data>60816c15</Data> 
<Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data> 
<Data>10.0.17763.2183</Data> 
<Data>12a65345</Data> 
<Data>e06d7363</Data> 
<Data>001235e2</Data> 
<Data>fa0</Data> 
<Data>01d7d57fa38520cb</Data> 
<Data>K:\redacted\redacted.exe</Data> 
<Data>C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data> 
<Data>03eae790-81b8-4040-aab4-6068440c4db0</Data> 
<Data /> 
<Data /> 
</EventData> 
</Event>
```

[image: Empty Crash Dump]

Comment: I presume you want the crash dump so you can tell which line of code in your app caused the fault?

Comment: Yes thats correct Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN notes one very important restriction: writing a minidump from inside a just-crashed process is not reliable. It's not clear from your question whether you're using a separate process to write the dumps ("redacted.exe"?), so this is definitely a possible cause.

Comment: Oh - this is interesting. @MSalters - what does it mean to use a separate process for dumps? (Apologies for my ignorance) The way I read it was simply Andy has a c++ app. It has crashed (in the windows kernelbase), and they expect a dump file but it wasn’t there.

Comment: @Jonny: The dump file needs to be written by a process. In theory you could try to write the dump file from inside the "crashed" process (typically from a vectored SEH handler) but it's safer to do it from an auxiliary process.

Comment: ah makes sense. If you don’t specify anything then does windows use a default implementation of a SEH handler?  I.e if you just do file project new in visual studio and create a console or win32 c++ app (and perhaps do a divide by 0 in code or something to test a crash). I don’t suppose there is any example code on msdn or similar?

Comment: @Jonny: Correct, Windows will catch the exception and show an error message.

Comment: Ta Gents - is this what an SEH ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp

Comment: Image added just to be clear :) 

So in effect we are saying that the standard handler had no chance to write the file?

Comment: @AndyP: The link you gave is indeed SEH, from the perspective of MSVC. From the perspective of Windows, it's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/structured-exception-handling. I think the "write a dump file " as default behavior for an unhandled SEH exception is a Windows setting. If you have Visual Studio installed, it can install itself as a just-in-time debugger. Windows will then give the memory contents to Visual Studio's debugger instead of writing them to a .dmp

Comment: Brilliant Help M Salters!  When I can work out how to close this question down I will and give some kudos :)

Comment: @AndyP: "Closing" a question on SO is something we do with questions that are off-topic or unanswerable, and that generally requires a vote. But you _can_ accept an answer (checkmark next to the score) so everyone else sees that there's no more input required.

Comment: @MSalters ta sir, tried to upvote but not allowed yet